# explain inheritance method override

Tags: c#, oop

Here are two classes :

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string result()
    {
        return "ClassA_Result";
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public string result()
    {
        return "ClassB_Result";
    }
}
```

When I create an instance of ClassB the result I'm getting is `ClassB_Result`. I'm expecting the result to be `ClassA_Result`

```
 ClassB objB = new ClassB();

 string b = objB.result();    //result is `ClassB_Result`
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `ClassA obj = new ClassB(); string b = obj.result();` ? (It still isn't polymorphic, of course)

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. When you instantiate ClassB, then call that instance, you will call that class' implementation. What is it that you are trying to do and why do you expect a call to B to call the implementation of A?

Comment: @RoyDictus Class A has a method called result, so I thought defining another method with same name in derived class would over ride the inherited class method.

Comment: Implementation of result in class A can be called by casting it (objB as ClassA).result();

Comment: @iJay: If it *did* override the inherited method, why would you expect the result to be `ClassA_Result`? Your expectations appear to be very confused - you're expecting it to be overridden when it's not, but you're *also* expecting the result to be the one you'd get if you didn't have the method in `ClassB` at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, you're not overriding the `result()` method - and indeed you can't, because it's not virtual.

The compiler should be giving you a warning like this:

> warning CS0108: 'ClassB.result()' hides inherited member 'ClassA.result()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Always *always* read the compiler warnings. They're there to help you.

You should have a `virtual` modifier on the method in `ClassA`, and the `override` modifier on the method in `ClassB`. I'd also encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions - I know this was just a sample, but it's worth following conventions even in dummy code. (`result` should be `Result`.)

Now even when you've fixed the code like that, you'll *still* get `ClassB_Result` - because you're creating an instance of `ClassB`. The difference would come if you write:

```
ClassA objB = new ClassB();
string b = objB.result();
```

With that snippet, in your current code it will give a result of `ClassA_Result` because the method isn't being called virtually. With the fixed code, it would give a result of `ClassB_Result` because the override in `ClassB` would be called. Currently, your method in `ClassA` is entirely irrelevant, because the compile-time type of `objB` is `ClassB`.

Answer (score 2):

Or use  new keyword in your B class

```
    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        new public string result()
        {
            return "ClassB_Result";
        }
    }
```

From MSDN -"When used as a declaration modifier, the new keyword explicitly hides a member that is inherited from a base class. When you hide an inherited member, the derived version of the member replaces the base class version. Although you can hide members without using the new modifier, you get a compiler warning. If you use new to explicitly hide a member, it suppresses this warning."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What ever you have done is method hiding not method overriding,

with your definitions for class A and B which is with method hiding, below code will get "ClassB_Result"

```
ClassB objB = new ClassB();
string b = obj.result();
```

but below will get "ClassA_Result"

```
ClassA obj = new ClassB();
string a = obj.result();
```

but with method  overriding, your class definitions need to be changed a bit where in class A the method should be marked as "virtual" and in class B the same method should be marked with override.

With method overriding, below both code snippets will get "ClassB_Result" only.

```
ClassB objB = new ClassB();
string b = obj.result();
```

and

```
ClassA obj = new ClassB();
string a = obj.result();
```